# SQL - Inserting text with line breakes into a column causes errors

Tags: javascript, sql-server, vbscript, textarea, line-breaks

I have a column in database with a type: nvarchar(300)

On a page, I have a text area with a maxsize limit = 300, allowing to enter 300 characters max:

```
<textarea id="txtDescription" maxlength="300" cols="70" rows="5"></textarea>
```

But for some reason, when I enter text with line breaks there, like this one:

```
 1. First.
 2. Second.
 3. Third.
```

The browser doesn't count the entered number of symbols right, it counts one line break as one extra character, but when I then insert this value into SQL column, it gives me a type mismatch error, apparently **because SQL counts one line break as two characters** and the maximum length is exceeded.

Now, because I don't know how many line breaks user will input there, is there any way to process input value so that it will be inserted into the database table correctly, without any errors? (Note: I'm using Javascript on a client side and classic ASP written on VBscript on server side).

So that I keep the limit of 300 characters max and wouldn't have to change the type of the column to nvarchar(MAX)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the carriage returns (`char(13)` or `\r`) and keep the line feeds (`char(10)` or `\n`).